# HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization（can not connect to database from springboot）

Tags: java, mysql, spring

everyone. Forgive me for my poor English and strange grammar. I'm just beginning to learn Java
I got an error when try to query database,the application can be booted successfully.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJcpM.png)
when I query the database through the API,the error occurred.

> 2021-02-03 13:15:46.693  INFO 3761 --- [nio-8088-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

> 2021-02-03 13:15:46.693  INFO 3761 --- [nio-8088-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'

> 2021-02-03 13:15:46.694  INFO 3761 --- [nio-8088-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
> Creating a new SqlSession
> Registering transaction synchronization for SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@c939991]

> 2021-02-03 13:15:46.759  INFO 3761 --- [nio-8088-exec-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...

> 2021-02-03 13:15:51.891 ERROR 3761 --- [nio-8088-exec-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: **Could not create connection to database server**. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

then i try to connect the local database via Navicat,succeed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPae4.png)

here is my application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8088
  tomcat:
    uri-encoding: UTF-8
    max-http-header-size: 80KB

spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  datasource:                                            # 数据源的相关配置
   type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource          # 数据源类型：HikariCP
   driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver          # mysql驱动
   url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo-shop?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=CST
  username: root
  password: 12345678
  hikari:
    connection-timeout: 30000       # 等待连接池分配连接的最大时长（毫秒），超过这个时长还没可用的连接则发生SQLException， 默认:30秒
    minimum-idle: 10                 # 最小连接数
    maximum-pool-size: 10           # 最大连接数
    auto-commit: true               # 自动提交
    idle-timeout: 600000            # 连接超时的最大时长（毫秒），超时则被释放（retired），默认:10分钟
    pool-name: DateSourceHikariCP     # 连接池名字
    max-lifetime: 1800000           # 连接的生命时长（毫秒），超时而且没被使用则被释放（retired），默认:30分钟 1800000ms
    connection-test-query: SELECT 1
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 512000     # 文件上传大小限制为500kb
      max-request-size: 512000  # 请求大小限制为500kb

mybatis:
  mapper-locations: classpath:mapper/*.xml      # mapper映射文件
  type-aliases-package: com.mooc.pojo          # 所有POJO类所在包路径
#  mapper-locations: classpath:mapper/*.xml      # mapper映射文件
  configuration:
    log-impl: org.apache.ibatis.logging.stdout.StdOutImpl


mapper:
  mappers: com.mooc.my.mapper.MyMapper
  not-empty: false    # 在进行数据库操作的的时候，判断表达式 username != null, 是否追加 username != ''
  identity: MYSQL
```

```
       <!-- mysql驱动 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mybatis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tk.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapper-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

What happened?:(

Answer (score 2):

problem solved
before

```
   url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo-shop?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=CST
  username: root
  password: 12345678
```

after

```
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo-shop?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=CST
  username: root
  password: 12345678
```